# How to prevent accidentally piping text to Vim?

Tags: terminal, linux, bash

I use Vim to edit the output of shell commands all the time. Appending the dash in this line is second nature:

```
$ ./some-command | vim -
```

But every once in a while I get distracted and forget:

```
$ ./some-command | vim
```

This typically causes Vim to hang, pegs one core at 100% CPU, and may disrupt the terminal. Is there a way to fool-proof Vim for me?

Comment: Create a shell script called `vim` that checks for at least one argument before invoking the real vim with the arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @chicks pointed out, you can place this script in your PATH:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ "$#" -ne 0 ]] || [[ -t 0 ]]; then
    exec vim "$@"
else
    exec vim -
fi
```

I am using a variant of this script in `~/bin/e` to open the current directory (`vim .`) when no argument is provided.

I guess you could also use a shell function:

```bash
v() { if [[ "$#" -ne 0 ]] || [[ -t 0 ]]; then vim "$@"; else vim -; fi; }
```